# Appium - Driver.source() showing android home page even with app on screen

Tags: appium, appium-android

I'm new on Appium, and I'm trying to make it work on a react-native app. I'm following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/how-to-do-end-to-end-e2e-testing-for-react-native-android-using-jest-and-appium-27d75e4d831b) but I have some issues.

I'm trying to find an element with `accessibilityLabel="testview"` but when I execute the code, I can't find this element. So, I put the command `console.log(await driver.source());` to see the XML code. Even with the app opened on the emulator, I get the XML code from the Android home page, but not the code from my app.

My test code is:

```
import wd from 'wd';

jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 60000;
const PORT = 4723;
const config = {
  platformName: 'Android',
  deviceName: 'Android Emulator',
  app: './android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk', // relative to root of project
  appPackage: 'com.example.android',
  appActivity: 'com.example.MainActivity'
};
const driver = wd.promiseChainRemote('localhost', PORT);

beforeAll(async () => {
  await driver.init(config);
  await driver.sleep(8000); // wait for app to load
})

test('appium renders', async () => {
  console.log(await driver.source());
  expect(await driver.hasElementByAccessibilityId('testview')).toBe(true);
});
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting this XML code instead of the XML code from my app? Is there any configuration that is wrong? I am using Windows, genymotion, the android emulator, and the uiautomator.

Comment: Do you have app-debug.apk apk in the folder /android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/?  Do your app have element with "testview" as automationID/conten-desc?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by changing the version of uiautomator used. I just added a line in the configuration:

```
const config = {
  platformName: 'Android',
  deviceName: 'Android Emulator',
  app: './android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk', // relative to root of project
  appPackage: 'com.example.android',
  appActivity: 'com.example.MainActivity'
  automationName: 'uiautomator2'
};
```